# strictly decresing sample eigenvalues

Tags: statistics

If we assume that the eigenvalues of covariance matrix are strictly decresing $\lambda_1>\cdots >\lambda_n$.

Under which conditions we can assume the same for the sample eigenvalues, that is,  $\hat{\lambda}_1>\cdots >\hat{\lambda}_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly positive definite and unequal (sample) variances.